# Unable to click on element defined in Div Class

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a mobile app testing using Eclipse. However, I am facing an issue where I can't perform a click() action.

This is my test code:

```
public class Firstflow {
    static DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    static AndroidDriver driver;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException{              
        dc.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5444");
        dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.mol.molwallet.uat");
        dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.mol.molwallet.module.start.SplashActivity");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), dc);
        driver.setLogLevel(Level.INFO);
        Thread.sleep(5000); 
        driver.findElement(By.className("_highlighter-box_619e8 _inspected-element-box_619e8")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='LOG IN']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Region']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Malaysia']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='etAccount']")).sendKeys("123456");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='NEXT']")).click();
    }
}
```

The line of code in question is the `driver.findElement(By.className("_highlighter-box_619e8 _inspected-element-box_619e8")).click();`

I need to click on the link "SKIP" as highlighted in the screenshot below. The element's detailed is also shown as per highlighted.
[image]

I have tried `By.xpath` and now `By.className`, both of which will result in the error `(Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.)`

Hope to have advice to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple.Use the dynamic xpath something like below in your code

//*[contains(text(),'Skip']

Comment: Is this syntax `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'SKIP')]")).click();` correct ? After using this, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: that is correct.but can you check your html code for 'skip' inner text.Expand the div tag and check whether "SKIP" text would be in small letters or capital letters.If possible can you post that screen shot after expanding DIV tag?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to paste page source as code, not as image, the chance you'll get comprehensive answer will be much higher so next time consider executing [driver.getPageSource()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource--) command and paste the text here.

As we cannot see the full page source I can give only a "blind shot": try using [normalize-space() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) like:

```
//div[normalize-space()='SKIP'] | //div/child::*[normalize-space()='SKIP'] | //div/descendant::*[normalize-space()='SKIP']
```

More information:

- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: @Dimitri, Sorry for the late reply as I was not around the last two days. Kindly find the xml file here [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DAS6u-bKJwndR_FjSkdfk3MP_xXhAiDJ) for your reference.

Comment: `//android.widget.TextView[@text='SKIP']`

Comment: USing By.xpath ?